# How to associate file extensions with my own Python script in Linux?

Tags: file-associations

I wrote Python script to open pickled figure files, called it `view_fig_pickle.py` and put it into `~/bin` directory.

Now how to associate it with file with endings '.fig.pickle'?

Comment: have you tried to edit `~/.local/share/applications/mimeapps.list ` ?

Answer (score 3):

Step 1: Create a new mime type

In `~/.local/share/mime/packages/` create a file `text-fig.pickle.xml` with content:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<mime-info xmlns='http://www.freedesktop.org/standards/shared-mime-info'>
  <mime-type type="text/fig.pickle">
    <comment>my new mime type</comment>
    <glob pattern="*.fig.pickle"/>
  </mime-type>
</mime-info>
```

With this xml file in place, update the mime type database:

```
update-mime-database ~/.local/share/mime
```

If you have the command `mimetype` installed on your system, you can do a quick verification:

```
touch test.fig.pickle
mimetype test.fig.pickle
  test.fig.pickle: text/fig.pickle
```

Step 2: Create a `.desktop` file for your application

In `~/.local/share/applications/` create a file `view_fig_pickle.desktop` with content:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Exec=view_fig_pickle.py %F
Icon=view_fig_pickle.png
Name=View Fig Pickle
Terminal=false
Type=Application
```

where

- `Exec` is your application, which is executable and in your path
- `Icon` is an icon in `~/.icons` (you can keep this entry even if the
  icon does not exist)
- `Name` is the text displayed in the context menu of your file manager

Step 3: Associate your application with your new mime type

```
xdg-mime default view_fig_pickle.desktop text/fig.pickle
```

Verify:

```
xdg-mime query default text/fig.pickle
  view_fig_pickle.desktop
```

and

```
xdg-open test.fig.pickle
```

This should open `test.fig.pickle` in `view_fig_pickle.py`, also if you click on the file in your file browser.

However, you might need to make the association also in your file manager (right-click the file, choose `Open with...`, and select `View Fig Pickle` from the `Other` submenu).

To revert this modification:

Step 1: Delete the mime type

```
rm ~/.local/share/mime/packages/text-fig.pickle.xml
update-mime-database ~/.local/share/mime
```

Step 2: Delete the association

edit `~/.local/share/applications/mimeapps.list` and delete the line with `text/fig.pickle=view_fig_pickle.desktop`

Step 3: Remove the obsolete `.desktop` file

```
rm .local/share/applications/view_fig_pickle.desktop
```